# $V^T=V(F_1^T,\ldots,F_r^t)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I'm reading Fulton's [Algebraic Curves book](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf) on page 19 he defines $V^T$:

[image]

I want to prove if $V=V(F_1,\ldots, F_r)$, then $V^T=V(F_1^T,\ldots,F_r^T)$, Is this true?

I need help

Thanks a lot!